# Issues With Temp Tables in RODBC

Tags: r, rodbc

I have the code below which I am trying to use to create a table with the datetime stamp for every minute of a year, then left join to another table, and finally use some tsql to create a new field in the final select statement that is returned.  The sql runs just fine in sql server, but when I try to run it in RODBC I get errors, an empty character vector, or a character vector with what look like sql server error messages.  I've seen some posts about using temp tables in RODBC and separating them with "go", or in to separate sqlQuery statements.  I've tried unsuccessfully separating the steps with "go", and I'm not sure separating the statement into several sqlQuery statements would work in this case since I'd like to use both temp tables in the final select statement with some tsql functions.  Any advice is very much appreciated.

```
Code:

library("forecast")
library("tseries")
library("sqldf")
library("manipulate")
library("caret")
library("qdapTools")
library("RODBC")
library("dplyr")
library("xts")




con<-odbcConnect("RsqlConnect")

dfETest<-sqlQuery(con,"

            create table #TempFM (dt datetime not null);
            declare @datestart datetime = '2015-01-01 00:00', @dateend datetime = '2015-12-31 23:59';

            while @datestart <= @dateend
            begin
            insert into #TempFM (dt)
            select dateadd(minute, number, @datestart)
            from master..spt_values 
            where
            type = 'p' and number between 0 and 1439
            and dateadd(minute, number, @datestart) <= @dateend;
            set @datestart = dateadd(minute, 1440, @datestart);
            end 


            select 
            dTime,                

            1 as CV

            into #TempP
            from TableM


            select DATEADD(hh,datepart(hour,dt), DATEADD(mi,(datepart(minute,dt)/15)*15,cast(cast(dt as DATE)as datetime))) as VTQ, 
            *
            from #TempFM f
            left join #TempP p on p.dTime = f.dt
            ")


Data:

dput(TableM[1:100,])
structure(list(dTime = structure(c(1435505100, 1424580900, 1423598220, 
1426616460, 1440028200, 1449095520, 1426370640, 1423697880, 1440517860, 
1426479960, 1428707940, 1450308780, 1449771840, 1437770880, 1433912820, 
1449501900, 1427121780, 1430257500, 1446993480, 1440373200, 1432256100, 
1426721700, 1449449340, 1422559320, 1423162920, 1422683580, 1423545300, 
1424242200, 1445704920, 1447931340, 1443834480, 1450638300, 1446287220, 
1451246520, 1449158280, 1447267260, 1448101560, 1449361860, 1450958520, 
1447351680, 1448352120, 1449038040, 1447534680, 1448908620, 1440340980, 
1443400980, 1448952120, 1448851680, 1448856540, 1447201440, 1448128440, 
1448061660, 1438615980, 1444851960, 1447698180, 1450836060, 1451323080, 
1447693140, 1447981980, 1440027300, 1449005220, 1446873960, 1451392260, 
1449064500, 1450879140, 1451177100, 1450883100, 1449081840, 1448165040, 
1443192720, 1442772900, 1447801140, 1444959300, 1446919980, 1447376220, 
1447702980, 1450558080, 1450360620, 1443759360, 1440593340, 1450672440, 
1441950840, 1449247140, 1447280580, 1449704160, 1451545800, 1445292540, 
1449862440, 1450046580, 1449707520, 1450376520, 1450904100, 1447016700, 
1445739720, 1449717180, 1445973000, 1438405920, 1450006500, 1443343800, 
1449465540), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), CV = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("dTime", "CV"), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What's wrong with using separate `sqlQuery` statements? I thought temp tables were persistent to a connection, not to a query/call (I could be wrong), in which case it shouldn't pose a problem. (If it does not work, it might be useful to edit your question with the errors you get, for whichever specific SQL command triggered it.)

Comment: @r2evans I'm getting things like: str(dfETest)
 chr [1:3] "42S22 207 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name  ...  I think the problem is with the first temp table I'm creating to store all the minutes in.  I've tried running just that query by itself in RODBC with no luck.